# Derivative of quotient of a formal power series

Tags: derivatives, power-series

Suppose $G(x)$ is a formal power series with invertible constant term.
How could I show that $$\Big(\frac{1}{G(x)}\Big)'= -\frac{G'(X)}{G^2(X)}$$

Comment: Isn't it simply a rule of finding a derivative of a ratio of two functions? I mean this thing: $\Big(\frac{F(x)}{G(x)}\Big)' = \frac{F'(x)G(x) - F(x)G'(x)}{G^2(x)}$, but here $F(x) = 1$, so we get the required equality.

Comment: Product rule. $$G(x)\cdot \biggl(\frac{1}{G(x)}\biggr) = 1.$$ Differentiate.

Comment: @EvgenyKovalev : No.  It's not about functions; it's about FORMAL power series, as opposed to CONVERGENT power series, which actually represent functions. $\qquad$

Comment: @AlexR. : You also should look at my comment above addressed to Evgeny Kovalev. $\qquad$

Answer (score 2):

(Just trying to find a different proof)

You want
$g^2(x)\left( \frac1{g(x)}\right)'
= - g'(x)
$.

Treating that as
one part of the
differentiating of a product,

\begin{align}
g^2(x)\left( \frac1{g(x)}\right)'
+(g^2(x))'\left( \frac1{g(x)}\right)
&=(g^2(x)\frac1{g(x)})' \\[10pt]
&=(g(x))'
\end{align}

so

\begin{align}
g^2(x)\left( \frac1{g(x)}\right)'
&=(g(x))'-(g^2(x))'\left( \frac1{g(x)}\right)\\[10pt]
&=(g(x))'-2g(x)g'(x)\left( \frac1{g(x)}\right)\\[10pt]
&=(g(x))'-2g'(x)\\[10pt]
&=-g'(x)
\end{align}

which is what you want.

Comment: I've tried align.I prefer array (as you may have noticed).